# Using ADF Web Activity for each row in a Query

Tags: foreach, azure-data-factory

Good Day!

I am pretty new to **ADF** and need some guidance on how to best accomplish using the **ADF Web Activity** for each record in a **query/view**. I have a system where we need to add new users daily.  I have built a query that returns what users are new and I would like to call a rest API to add their accounts in other systems.  Today, I accomplish this in a java program where we get a result set and then iterate through each row and call the *API*.

I am attempting to replicate this in **ADF** and running into not understand how to accomplish this. The `ForEach` activity does not appear to be able to connect to a dataset or query.  I have seen other examples of using the `ForEach` when you are building a parameter list and understand how that would work.  (for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal.)

Can anyone give me some direction on how you run an activity for each row in a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to do this using the Lookup Activity and then passing the output of the lookup to the foreach activity.  Here is a my pipeline:

[image: AdF Pipeline with Lookup ad ForEach activity]

When passing the data from the Lookoup to the ForEach look you wan to set the ForEach items to "@activity('Lookup1').output.value"  If you use the 'add dynamic content' selection and pick the output data sent ADF sets the value to @activity('Lookup1').output which will through a weird error about the length function when you run it.

In my research I found this demo to be very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROq5mVrZPY0